# how to call a php function from address bar?

Tags: php, function, url, post, get

how can i call function declared in  my php file from address bar?
I already tried appending function name with site address  but it didn't called the function..

```
http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?writeMessage
```

myfile.php:

```
<?php
  /* Defining a PHP Function */
  function writeMessage()
  {
  echo "You are really a nice person, Have a nice time!";
  }
  /* Calling a PHP Function */
  writeMessage();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check presence of GET parameter in URL and call function accordingly:

```
if(isset($_GET['writeMessage'])){
   writeMessage();
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Another example of the case. Also agreed with hanky here, good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way that i would use given that you dont have too many functions is to use a if statement at the top of the php file and check the parameter of the url.

Lets say url:

```
http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?writeMessage
```

Turn it into:

```
http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?function=writeMessage
```

code:

```
<?php
  $function = $_GET['function'];
  if($function == "writeMessage") {
    // writeMessage();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesnt, especially not in that way. For me, it seems to be a horrible idea to call PHP Functions from the address bar, but if you insist:

append the function name to your url like this:

```
http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?func=writeMessage
```

And in the PHP File:

```
<?php
    $func = filter_var($_GET["func"]);
    call_user_func($func);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?writeMessage=1
```

And:

```
<?php
 /* Defining a PHP Function */
 function writeMessage()
 {
    echo "You are really a nice person, Have a nice time!";
 }
 /* Calling a PHP Function */
 if(isset($_GET['writeMessage']) && $_GET['writeMessage'] == 1){
   writeMessage();
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

function writeMessage() {
    echo "You're a nice person";
}

$writeMessageArg = $_GET['writeMessage']; /* grabs the argument from the URL */

if (isset($writeMessageArg)) {
    writeMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: how differ answer you have from OP's

Comment: Is it not obvious? I have a new variable defined as `$_GET['writeMessage']` and then I check to see if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic approach

```
<?php

$q = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

function TestFunc() {
    echo "TestFunc() called.";
}

$q();

?>
```

You can call the TestFunc() by entering the following url in the address bar:

> http://myWebSite.com/myFile.php?TestFunc